# creating a structure and displaying them

Tags: c, struct

```
Date *date_create(char *datestr);  
struct datestr { 
    int date; 
    int month; 
    int year;  
} 

char *datestr = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*size);
```

- `date_create` creates a data structure from `datestr`
- `datestr` is expected to be of the form "dd/mm/yyyy"

Basically I'm having some problems with the create portion i need some help in creating let's say an input 02/11/2013 and then this data will be added into the pointer and then i have to display them in terms of blocks such as 02 for date, 11 for month and 2013 for year... any ideas how to continue from here? i will have to use a malloc function?

Comment: [A good book on C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) would be a worthwhile investment at this point.

Comment: You don't need pointers at all. The compiler will happily copy structures for you in assignments or as return values.

Comment: howdo u continue from here? i got myself a c book thought but im still kinda confused

Answer (score 0):

- Use [strtok](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok) and the [atoi](http://linux.die.net/man/3/atoi)/strtol family to extract your integer values from the string
- Alternatively you can use [scanf](http://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf) to do this
- Use malloc to allocate a struct of your type and fill the fields with the extracted values
- Return the allocated pointer to your struct

Answer (score 0):

maybe something like this

```
typedef struct 
{ 
    int day; 
    int month; 
    int year;  
} 
datestructure;

datestructure date_create(const char *datestr)
{
  datestructure ret; // return value
  char* datestrDup = strdup(datestr); // alloc/copy

  ret.day = strtok(datestrDup,"/"); 
  ret.month = strtok(NULL,"/");
  ret.year = strtok(NULL," ");

  free(datestrDup);
  return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, and try to work out what it's doing with your book:

```
typedef struct _dates
{ 
   int date; 
   int month; 
   int year;
} DateStr;

DateStr * date_create(char *datestr);

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   DateStr *result;
   char inputString[100];
   printf("Enter the date: ");

    if (gets(inputString))
    {
        result = date_create(inputString);

        if (result)
        {
            printf("Parsed date is Date:%d, Month:%d, Year:%d",result->date, result->month, result->year);
        }
    }

    return 0;
} 


DateStr * date_create(char *datestr)
{
    DateStr * date = (DateStr *)malloc(sizeof(DateStr));

    if (date)
    {
        sscanf(datestr, "%d/%d%/%d",&date->date, &date->month, &date->year);
    }

    return date;
}
```